# Stored procedure with a return parameter - "ODBC driver does not support the requested properties"?

Tags: stored-procedures, vb6, odbc

I have followed the previous code and try to call a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
    @in char(5) = '     ',
    @out smallint = 0 output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @out = 100
END
```

Then in the VB6, i try to request this stored procedure by below

```
   strConn = "Select * from TBL where 1=2"
    Set rsCmd = objCCS.ExecuteStatement(strConn, adUseServer, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic)
    Dim rdoqry_data2 As ADODB.Command
    Set rdoqry_data2 = CreateObject("Adodb.command")
    Set rdoqry_data2 = rsCmd.ActiveCommand
    rdoqry_data2.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    rdoqry_data2.CommandText = "sp_test"
    rdoqry_data2(0).Direction = adParamReturnValue
    rdoqry_data2(1).Direction = adParamInput
    rdoqry_data2(2).Direction = adParamOutput
    rdoqry_data2(2).Type = adSmallInt
    rdoqry_data2(1) = "123"
    rdoqry_data2.Execute
```

But it flow an exception **ODBC driver does not support the requested properties**.

Can anyone find the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does the exception appear? I guess the exception is the result of calling the procedure sp_test and not the result of executing objCCS.ExecuteStatement, right?

My approach to call the stored procedure sp_test from VB6 would be:

```
Dim rdoqry_data2 As ADODB.Command
Set rdoqry_data2 = New ADODB.Command
With rdoqry_data2
    Set .ActiveConnection = (your connection object)
    .Parameters.Append rdoqry_data2.CreateParameter("@in", adVarchar, adParamInput, 5, "123")
    .Parameters.Append rdoqry_data2.CreateParameter("@out", adSmallInt, adParamOutput, 2)
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "sp_test"
    .Execute
End With
```

First you have to create the command object and assign the connection object to it. In this case you need two parameter objects. First parameter is an input parameter with a maximum size of 5 bytes (char(5)) and the content "123". Second parameter is an output parameter with a max. size of 2 bytes (smallint). Finally you have to tell the command object to call a stored procedure with the name "sp_test".

Does this work for you?

Comment: it is VB6, not sure if linq is supported

Comment: the parameter is fine as it worked if I changed the sql provider from MSDASQL to SQL one. the only question is why provider MSDASQL cannot operate normal on the issued code.